# I can't find TauDEM in the providers under processing

Tags: qgis, taudem

I am trying to add TauDEM, after installing it as instructed I can't find it Under the providers in QGIS 3.4 although I can under earlier versions (also can't install them for other reasons)

Comment: Ive tried to install and use TauDEM in QGIS 3.10, I couldnt get it to work successfully. Have you tried Whitebox Tools? I have found that there are more tools there and they work better.

Answer (score 5):

TauDEM was removed from QGIS 3 so you will not be able to find it in processing. However you can use it by installing it manually as mentioned on [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/taudem/index.html) (follow [this link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/taudem/index.html) for documentation in English).

> Please remember that Processing contains only the interface description, so you need to install TauDEM 5.0.6 by yourself and configure Processing properly.

More information in the [TauDEM for Processing documentation](https://plugins.bruy.me/processing-taudem.html)